# Caliper output Matchit

Tags: r, causality, propensity-scores, matching

I was examining output of the `MatchIt` package in R using this code

```
library(MatchIt)
data(lalonde)

matched.output <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + nodegree + 
                    married + re74 + re75, method = "nearest", data = lalonde, caliper = .1)

matched.output$call$caliper
matched.output$caliper
```

Why are there 2 different caliper values inside the object? How would you describe these 2 values when writing up your findings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caliper in the call to `matchit()` is specified in **standardized units** by default. This can be controlled by the `std.caliper` argument, which is set to `TRUE` by default. The caliper displayed in the output object is the caliper in **raw units**, which is important for interpretation since it is not immediately clear how standardized units correspond to raw units. For example, a caliper of .1 standard deviations of the propensity score doesn't tell you how close units are on the propensity score itself. This is especially true when placing calipers on covariates directly (i.e., rather than on the propensity score). If you set `std.caliper = FALSE`, so that the argument supplied to `caliper` corresponds to raw units, you will see the two outputs line up.